# Can I set a "scope" for dependencies bundled by webpack?

Tags: reactjs, webpack, survivejs

I use webpack to to bundle a ReactJS component. This ReactJS component has some dependencies and one of them is jQuery. Right now I just run webpack to create the bundled script.

Now I'd like to integrate the bundled script (representing my ReactJS component) into a legacy application. This application uses another version of jQuery (by directly importing the jQuery javascript file).

I wonder if this can lead to any problems because of having two jQuery versions in one application.
I don't really understand how webpack handles the dependencies in the bundle. Are they kind of "scoped" in the bundle so that they don't affect parts of my legacy application? Or is there any way to do so?

My webpack.config:

```
var CopyWebpackPlugin = require('copy-webpack-plugin');
module.exports = {
    entry: "./js/components/Application.js",
    output: {
        path: "./target/dist",
        filename: "application.js"
    },
    module: {
        loaders: [
            {
              loader: "babel-loader",
              test: /\.js$/,
              exclude: /(node_modules|dist|__tests__)/
            },
            {
              loader: "style-loader!css-loader",
              test: /\.css$/
            },
            {
                test: /\.(jpg|png)$/,
                loader: 'url-loader',
                include: /img/
            }
        ]
    },

    devtool: 'source-map',
    plugins: [
      new CopyWebpackPlugin([
        {from: 'static/index.html'},
        {from: 'css/*.css'},
        {from: 'fonts/*'},
          {from: 'img/*.*'},
        {from: 'data/*'}
      ])
    ]
};
```

Comment: If you want to bundle up a component on its own to be reusable in multiple apps, you're better off exporting it as a [library](https://webpack.github.io/docs/configuration.html#output-library) (most likely in [UMD format](https://webpack.github.io/docs/configuration.html#output-librarytarget) for maximum compatibility). You can then use [externals](https://webpack.github.io/docs/configuration.html#externals) to depend on libraries/modules being provided by the consumer rather than your library.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. The problem is that the consumer app has a very old jQuery version (and I cannot change this right now). So using this old version as an external might cause problems in the component. That's why I'd like to have two jQuery versions.

Comment: Ah, I see. Then I'd probably still export as a library (just so you can `require` it in the consumer bundle), but leave jQuery as part of the library bundle - I don't think they'll overlap, as Webpack uses numerical IDs for dependencies behind the scenes. Alternatively, you could possibly use [aliases](https://webpack.github.io/docs/configuration.html#resolve-alias) to have the newer jQuery version referred to by a different name (e.g. `require("jquery3")`, or something like that).

Comment: Good to hear that they shouldn't overlap! I tried to find information about this but I didn't anything. Do you have a reference for this? Maybe I just overread it. Using an `alias` might help - I'll read the documentation about this.